# Embedded Twitter Widget Height issue

Tags: css, twitter

I am trying to add the Twitter widget to my website but I am having a problem with the height of the widget. Sometimes it works, other times it ignores the height value and stretches the page so that there is a lot of empty space at the bottom (stretches the widget to 7847px). I have tried adding height within the code and setting the DIV height but it still does it. This is the code I am using from Twitter

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-chrome="nofooter noheader noborders noscrollbar transparent" height='350' data-tweet-limit="5" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/Talk_AVFC/villa-players" data-widget-id="362602509207994368">Tweets from @Talk_AVFC/villa-players</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Anybody have this issue and know a fix?

Demo of issue is here http://richardawarner.co.uk/astonvillastuff/ (on the Twitter tab)

Comment: Don't you have to set the height and width in Twitter when creating new widgets now? After that I thought you couldn't change the height?

Comment: Changed the height on Twitter but still does it. I have included a link in original post where you can see.

Comment: The iframe has no height set on it at the moment. When I change the height to something like 300, it takes it fine. You need to give it some height.

Comment: How do I give the iframe height? I have placed height="350" and it doesn't work properly. Works for the first time but when refresh the page, it stretches.

Comment: Have you put height:'350' or height="350"?

Comment: I have used height="350" but for some reason it ignores it.

Comment: If you create the widget in the twitter website widget area, it'll give you the most up to date version of the widget and you can set height in it there.

Comment: I created another widget, height works fine until set the amount of tweets to appear. I add data-tweet-limit="5" which causes it to stretch.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer warnerr. You still can't use both at the same time it seems.

Answer (score 15):

The maximum width and height can be set by adding data attributes to the link:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="350" .... >
```

> Set the height of a displayed widget, overriding the value stored with
>   the widget ID. Must be greater than 200 pixels.
>
> Note: the height parameter does not apply when a tweet-limit parameter
>   is specified

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/parameters

Comment: I know this is an older posting and you came in late... but this should really be the answer! After searching and searching through many methods I knew their had to be an easier way... and sure enough you provided it!!

Comment: This is the right answer. The solution for the question on this post specifically (setting the height of the box) would be to add `data-height="350"`

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs @MarcosBuarque this isn't the right answer as it does not work as the OP has specified the parameter `data-tweet-limit="5"`

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove If you look at it he set height="350" versus the given answer here which I have verified that works as data-height="350"

Answer (score 2):

Target the .twitter-timeline class in CSS and declare its height

```
.twitter-timeline {
    height: 350px !important;
}
```